# Exercise on group actions

Tags: permutations, group-actions

Let be $A:=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4:=\{0,1,2,3\}$

Let s: $\mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow S_A$ a group action 
and $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+_4)$ where the operation is the addition modulo $4$.

1.Define $s_2:=(2)$ 
show that $s_2$ can be either the identity $e_A$ element or that the permutation $s_2$ has order $2$

Since $s$ is a group homomorphism:
$$s(2+2)=s(2)\circ (2)$$
Since $2+2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$,$s$ map the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ to the idendity element in $S_A$
therefore $s(2)=s_2=e_4$ and it has order $2$ unless $s_2 = e_A$ and therefore it has order $1$

2.Assume $s_2 \ne e_A$ (identity element) and define s1. Show that $s_1$ has order $4$.

As above, we can see that $s(1+1+1+1)=s_1 \circ s_1 \circ s_1 \circ s_1= s(0)=e_A$ and therefore the order of $s_1$ is $4$.

3.Does exist a group action $s$: $\mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow S_A$ such that $s_2=(ab)$?

Suggestions for question 3?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The permutation $s_2$ is the square of the permutation $s_1$. So it must be an even permutation, but a single transposition is odd.